# TLS implementation: (Using LibreSSL library) Failing handshake on client side when server certificate has wildcard SAN of type: *test.example.com

Tags: ssl, wildcard, handshake, libressl

**Problem:**

Server:
Subject Alternative Name(SAN) in server certificate: ***test.example.com**

Client:
Server Name Indicator(SNI) given from client side: **mytest.example.com**

Result: **handshake fail!**

---

Although for similar scenario,

Subject Alternative Name(SAN) in server certificate: ***.example.com**

Client:
Server Name Indicator(SNI) given from client side: **mytest.example.com**

Result: **handshake successful!**

---

**Query:**

I **need to conduct successful handshake for** SAN ***test.example.com.**
I'm guessing Openbsd must have an option to make the first match (which is failing now) valid. Can someone please help me with this.

---

**What RFC has to say: (RFC 6125 Sec: 6.4.3)**
The client **MAY** match a presented identifier in which the wildcard character is not the only character of the label (e.g., baz*.example.net and *baz.example.net and b*z.example.net would be taken to match baz1.example.net and foobaz.example.net and buzz.example.net, respectively). However, the client SHOULD NOT attempt to match a presented identifier where the wildcard character is embedded within an A-label or U-label [IDNA-DEFS] of an internationalized domain name [IDNA-PROTO].

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As the RFC says, the client MAY match. Most probably this particular client does not. If you want to have portable code, then you should not rely on this behavior. With that said, I don't know if libressl has an option to change that.

Comment: This question does not provide any code to reproduce the problem. Note that the specific behavior you describe is traditionally only done for HTTPS, i.e. wildcard verification in other protocols (LDAP, SMTP, ...) either did not support wildcards at all or required the asterisk to match the full label instead of only a part. The MAY instead of SHOULD or even MUST in the RFC reflects this.

Comment: @g_bor Actually I'm coding both client and server TLS  communication using libressl, and its a requirement that these kinds of SAN are  validated from client side. I guess I should have written it in query itself, my bad. Thanks though.

Comment: @s-ghansiala: If you need help with the behavior of your code then please provide code to reproduce your issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Steffen Ulliich, thanks for you reply. I guess your first comment almost solves my problem. I'm using DICOM protocol. As you suggested in your comment, I think the protocol itself is not supporting this kind of wildcard usage. Still if this inference can be confirmed, it will be a great help.
Thanks for your second comment too, the link is helpful, but I think your previous comment shall be enough, code won't be required. 
Thanks again!